# Change Character in folder name where only that character exist

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to change a - character to a _ character in the the root folder structure.

This is the situation.
e:\folder\bpo-v3\ext\ext\file.name
e:\folder\testopject\ext\ext\file.name

I use the code

```
$RootPath = "e:\folder\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 0 | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '-','_'}
```

This code work fine but i am getting a error on all the folder that do not have the - character.
What do I miss in de code to prevent that?

Comment: change `Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 0` to `Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Filter '*-*' -Directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to test the name to see if it contains the "-" character. Use [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) (alias: where or ?):

```
$RootPath = "e:\folder\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 0 |
    Where-Object Name -match '-' |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '-','_' }
```

But `...-Recurse -Depth 0...` is equivalent to no recursion, so your code simplifies to:

```
$RootPath = "e:\folder\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory |
    Where-Object Name -match '-' |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '-','_' }
```

And if you're working interactively at the console, you can shorten using aliases and taking advantage of positional parameters:

```
$RootPath = "e:\folder\"
gci $RootPath -ad | ? Name -match '-' | ren -NewName { $_.Name -replace '-','_' }
```

Comment: Thank you both, it works

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. Thanks for marking my reply as 'Answer'. Could you please give it an upvote as well.